# Output of vc_link in Backend of wpBakery faulty

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

I have a strange display and I don't know how to display it correctly.
When entering the link looks ok. But after saving it will be a long cryptic link.
In the frontend everything works and looks good.

Where is the mistake?

[Backend Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk1qf.jpg)

Below is the code

```
function darkteaser_vc_map_init() {

$settings = array(
    'name'      => __( 'kleine Teaserbox mit Bild', 'js_composer' ),        // shortcode name
    'base'      => 'my_darkteaser_element',                         // shortcode base [my_darkteaser_element.php]
    'category'  => __( 'Meine Elemente', 'js_composer' ),   // param category tab in add elements view
    'icon'      => get_template_directory_uri() . '/image/darkteaser.png',   // Simply pass url to your icon here
    'description'   => __( 'kleine Teaserbox mit Bild und Text', 'js_composer' ),       // element description in add elements view

    'show_settings_on_create' => false,
    // don't show params window after adding
    'weight'                  => - 5,
    // Depends on ordering in list, Higher weight first
    
    'html_template'           => dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/vc_templates/my_darkteaser_element.php',
    // if you extend VC within your theme then you don't need this, VC will look for shortcode template in "wp-content/themes/your_theme/vc_templates/my_darkteaser_element.php" automatically. In this example we are extending VC from plugin, so we rewrite template

    'front_enqueue_css'       => preg_replace( '/\s/', '%20', plugins_url( 'assets/front_enqueue_css.css', __FILE__ ) ),
    // This will load extra css file in frontend editor (when you edit page with VC)

    'params' => array(
        array(
            'type'          => 'attach_image',
            'class'         => 'teaserboxPicDunkel',
            'heading'       => __( 'Bild auswählen', 'js_composer' ),
            'param_name'    => 'bildteaser',
            'value'         => __(''),
            'description'   => 'Bild für Teaserbox hinzufügen.'
        ),
        array(
            'type'        => 'textarea_html',
            'holder'      => 'div',
            'class'       => 'teaserboxtextDunkel',
            'heading'     => __( 'Text eingeben', 'js_composer' ),
            'param_name'  => 'content', //param_name for textarea_html must be named "content"
            'value'       => __( '', 'js_composer' ),
            'description' => __( 'Text für Teaserbox.', 'js_composer' )
        ),
        array(
            'type'        => 'vc_link',
            'holder'      => 'div',
            'class'       => 'teaserboxbuttonDunkel',
            'heading'     => __( 'Link setzen', 'js_composer' ),
            'param_name'  => 'linkteaser',
            'value'       => __( '', 'js_composer' ),
            'description' => 'Link zur Seite'
        ),
    )
);
vc_map( $settings );
```

}
add_action('vc_after_init', 'darkteaser_vc_map_init');